# Crop a custom region in image Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Hi I have image i would like to crop a custom region in the image which is as shown in the example,

Original image:

[image: Original image]

The mask :
[image: This is the the mask of the object in the image]

I would to crop the original image by the shape of the mask and save it .. how would i do it?

Comment: By "crop" do you mean remove the information that is given by the mask from the original image, or to create a new image that is smaller than the original and the information in the mask does not appear?  Cropping implies a rectangular region that should be selected from the original image but this region is not rectangular.

Comment: @rayryeng hi, i want to crop and keep the region and remove other information. I want only the region from original image. Ya its not rectangular but how to get as same as the mask designed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use bitwise AND operation to solve the problem.

Firstly in the mask image, remove the red line and then make sure that region you want is of white(255) colour and the remaining is of black(0) colour.

Also check that the mask image should be a three-channel image(White - (255, 255, 255); Black - (0, 0, 0)). If it is not, you can convert it from 1 channel to 3 channel image keeping the white-black colour information by -

```
# Read mask image by cv2.imread("mask.jpg") - without -1 flag
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Now you can perform a simple bitwise operation -

```
mask_output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
```

"mask_output" will contain the desired output. Also, the speed of the bitwise operation is fast. If the mask is stored as explained above, then this code will become a one-liner code after reading the mask image and the coloured image.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully the mask that you provided has an alpha channel where the interior of the region you want masked out is defined within the alpha channel.  Therefore, read in the image with the alpha channel intact, then use this to remove the pixels in this region:

Supposing your mask is stored `mask.png` and your image is stored in `image.png`, you can do:

```py
img = cv2.imread('image.png', -1)
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png', -1)

mask = mask[...,3] > 0
mask = np.repeat(mask[..., None], img.shape[2], axis=2)

masked_out = img.copy()
masked_out[mask] = 0
cv2.imshow('Masked Out', masked_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('masked_out.png', masked_out)
```

We read in the original image and corresponding mask.  We then look at the alpha channel and threshold it so that any non-zero pixels create a binary image such that non-zero values are `True` and `False` otherwise.  We then create a 3D version of this so that the mask is duplicated for as many channels as there are in the input image.  We then set the locations in the mask that are `True` in the mask to all zero so that we make them black pixels.  We finally display the image to the screen, then write the image to screen after you push any key.

If you're not comfortable with the 3D mask, you can use broadcasting and simply multiply the **inverse** of the mask with the input image:

```py
img = cv2.imread('image.png', -1)
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png', -1)

mask = mask[...,3] == 0
masked_out = img * (mask[...,None].astype(img.dtype))
cv2.imshow('Masked Out', masked_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('masked_out.png', masked_out)
```

Comment: how can i print out and save the image? I mean the image that has been processed

Comment: You can just show it, or save it to disk.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: ya good thank you .. ok how can i get that area has removed i mean if look at the image that saved you will see road and trees but the area with mask is black. so how can make the area that black with information and the road and trees remove. just reflect it .

Comment: Now I think I know.  Would you want to use inpainting?  https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html.  You can fill in the pixels of the mask with nearby ones along the edge, but it won't be a reflection.  Please note that this is nowhere near what you were asking before.  Cropping / removing regions and filling in / inpainting are two completely different problems.

Comment: actually I just want the top red car region in the original image. I dont want to inpaint the image

Comment: Every time I ask for clarification I get more confused. I'm gonna leave this alone. Good luck!